# Date filtering returning wrong results - timezone issue?

Tags: datetime, ecommerce, timezone

I'm running into an issue where incorrect results are being returned when filtering Craft Commerce orders by date in a template. Can anyone help? I cannot figure out what is going on.

**FACTS:**

- Craft install is using `America/Denver` for timezone.
- I'm passing dates via the query string with this format: `YYYY-mm-dd`
- PHP version is 7.1.
- Problem timestamp from the DB is (2017-11-10 00:14:04)... this doesn't match the screenshot below because I've been fiddling with dates.

---

This is my reduced code:

```
{% set start = "2017-11-09" | date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', 'America/Denver')  %}
{% set end = "2017-11-09" | date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', 'America/Denver') %}
{% set orders = craft.commerce.orders.dateOrdered('and', '>= ' ~ start, '<= ' ~ end).find() %}

{% for order in orders %}
    {{ order.dateOrdered | date('Y-m-d H:i:s e') }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

---

This is the returned data with the incorrect entry:
[image]

Comment: FWIW, `date('Y-m-d')` is YYYY-MM-DD (zero-padded double digits for month and day), not YYYY-M-D. Not sure if that would make a difference or not, but it might affect the variables you're setting in the first two lines.

Comment: @Sandwich so the date being passed via the query string would need to be `2017-11-09`, correct? Or the date format character would be changed from d to j like so: `date('Y-m-j')`, yes?

Comment: @Natetronn Yes to the first, and I can't recommend ever using single digits for anything time-related for the second. ;)

Comment: Thank you for this suggested direction... going to did into it right now. I thought I was mitigating it because I was changing to the required format before submitting the query. Will report back.

Comment: Same results after adjusting the format for the date I'm sending to the page. I'm updating my question to reflect the changed date format.

Comment: If you output the raw timestamps for those orders and run them through some online timestamp converter, what does it say? Also, it could be that the PHP version has timezone-related bugs, so that might be worth looking into.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&order_by=id&direction=DESC&limit=30&package_name[]=Date%2Ftime+related

Comment: PHP version is 7.1 and the problem timestamp from the DB is (2017-11-10 00:14:04)

Comment: I'm looking through the PHP bug list but honestly isn't a little overwhelming. I don't know what I'm looking for since I can't 100% explain what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you're running into this same issue: [Using user-selectable timezones to show localized post dates](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18102/using-user-selectable-timezones-to-show-localized-post-dates)

Not terribly pretty, but as a workaround, you can do something like this:

```
{% set start = date("2017-11-09 00:00:00")|date_modify("+7 hours")|date('Y-m-d h:i:s')  %}
{% set end = date("2017-11-09 23:59:59")|date_modify("+7 hours")|date('Y-m-d h:i:s')  %}

{# +7 hours is because America/Denver is UTC-7, but would need to be adjusted to +6 hours when observing daylight savings time #} 

{% set orders = craft.commerce.orders.dateOrdered('and', '>= ' ~ start, '<= ' ~ end).find() %}

{% for order in orders %}
    {{ order.dateOrdered | date('Y-m-d H:i:s e') }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, note that this should "just work" in the upcoming Craft 3 as well.

There might be a cleaner way to do this using [@carlcs's workaround](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/18110/57), but I'm not seeing it at the moment.

Comment: Many thanks to Brad for tracking down a fix. I'd imagine most people who are filtering results by date are in fact getting incorrect results on the very edges of the date range since they aren't using a hardcoded UTC offset.